# Format vertically maintaining first column

Tags: grep, sed, format

It's been a long time since I've used grep or sed but I think this can be done.  How do I take a csv and format it vertically while maintaining/replicating the first columns.

```
Ex.
Input:
A, 1, 2, 3
B, 1, 2, 3
C, 1, 2, 3

Output:
A, 1
A, 2
A, 3
B, 1
B, 2
B, 3
C, 1
C, 2
C, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with `sed`, or maybe some versions of `grep`, however, using `awk` you can very elegantly express what you want to accomplish:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F, '
    BEGIN {
        OFS=","
    }
    {
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            print $1, $i
        }
    }
' <<EOF
A, 1, 2, 3
B, 1, 2, 3
C, 1, 2, 3
EOF
```

If you want the script to take filenames or standard input, replace the "here document" (everything from the `<<` to the end of the file) with:

```
"$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution.

```
sed -r ':a;s/([A-Z],)( [0-9]),( [0-9])/\1\2\n\1\3/;ta' <<<'A, 1, 2, 3
B, 1, 2, 3
C, 1, 2, 3'
A, 1
A, 2
A, 3
B, 1
B, 2
B, 3
C, 1
C, 2
C, 3
```